# how can i filter a array in Vue3

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, quasar-framework

I am new to Vue3.

I have to filter a array with same item and push results into another array

My array is

```
let list = [
  {"name":"1000","properties":{"item":"1","unit":"DZN"}},
  {"name":"2000","properties":{"item":"1","unit":"CTN"}},
  {"name":"3000","properties":{"item":"2","unit":"DZN"}},
  {"name":"4000","properties":{"item":"3","unit":"CTN"}}
]
```

I need corresponding name with condition `item =1` in another array.

Result array will be similar to `[{"name":"1000", "unit":"DZN"}, {"name":"2000", "unit":"CTN"}]`

TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to create an array of objects with *name* and *unit* attributes from records which have *item* values equal to 1. To do that you have to first filter an array to get only records which have desired value of *item* and then map those values to create a new array of objects.

Here is an example:

```js
let list = [
  {"name":"1000","properties":{"item":"1","unit":"DZN"}},
  {"name":"2000","properties":{"item":"1","unit":"CTN"}},
  {"name":"3000","properties":{"item":"2","unit":"DZN"}},
  {"name":"4000","properties":{"item":"3","unit":"CTN"}}
]

const filteredList = list.filter((e) => e.properties.item === "1").map((e) => { return {name: e.name, unit: e.properties.unit}});
console.log(filteredList);
```

If this is a Vue3 reactive variable remember to add **.value** before filter() method to make it work

Comment: Thank you. How i get  unit too in the filteredList

Comment: @SonaRijesh If you want to create an array of objects with _name_ and _unit_ attributes you must change the callback inside .map() method. It should looks something like that: .map((e) => { return {name: e.name, unit: e.properties. unit}}); I updated my answer so you can check how it works